# Form still submit when return false (Can't see the error)

Tags: javascript, html

I searched on stackoverflow and find some answers, but I tried everything.
Maybe it is just a small, or a few small mistakes, but I can't find them.

I also tried on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmee93/U59LJ/)!

```
<form class="search" onsubmit="return false;" method="get" action="index.html">
    <input class="text" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = this.defaultValue;}" onfocus="if(this.value == this.defaultValue){this.value = '';}" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }" value="Nachname" name="inputNachname" />
    <input class="text" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = this.defaultValue;}" onfocus="if(this.value == this.defaultValue){this.value = '';}" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }" value="Vorname" name="inputVorname" />
    <input type="hidden" value="search" name="query" />
    <button id="searchButton2" onmouseover="this.style.cursor = 'pointer';" onclick="form.submit();" value="Go" type="button">SUCHE</button>
</form>
```

I want to have a function, which returns false:

```
<form class="search" onsubmit="return go_search();" method="get" action="index.html">
```

and this is the function:

```
function go_search(){
    alert('abort');
    return false;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmee93/Eh4E8/)

Maybe anyone can find some mistakes or find a better way to do this?

Comment: At first glance of the code, it seems to be doing what it should be.  Can you edit your question and describe both what *is* happening and what you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your fiddle.

1. Your JavaScript function was wrapped in a window.load handler putting it in the wrong scope. Just putting it in the head will suffice.
2. Your button had the type button, not submit. The `onclick="form.submit();"` in your button was running and submitting the form since *it* was triggering the submission, instead of triggering the form's submit handler (`onsubmit="return go_search();"`). Changing the button's type from button to submit will fix that.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Eh4E8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to lose the onSubmit tag.  Just returning it FALSE won't exactly acheive what you are going for.  It seems you want to call a function that MAY return "false" if validation fails.  Here is a good method for handling that.

You need to attach the function call to your submit button

```
onclick="go_search()"
```

And inside your function, make the form submit if you'd like (after validation).

```
function go_search(){
    alert('abort');
    if (youWantToSubmit==true) {
     form.submit();
     }
}
```

Even this won't work 100% because your form has no name or ID.  You need to add those, and use a more correct call like:

```
document.getElementByID("[formID]").submit();
```

Comment: Not true. Returning false from an onsubmit handler on a form *will* prevent the form from being submitted, as long as the form is being submitted normally (e.g. from an actual submit button) rather than programmatically. @j08691's answer is correct

Comment: Ok.  Be that as it may, he's still handling it wrong.  
Why would you submit a "return false"? I was trying to illustrate a better way to handle the behaviour he is looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *submit* a "return false". I would assume he's trying to write a validation function and in testing he hardwired it to return false. There is nothing wrong with that approach - that's the whole reason the mechanism is there. The actual problems here were (1) the handler wasn't visible because it was defined in a function scope and (2) it wasn't being called because the form was being submitted programatically instead of having a submit button

Comment: But the main issue I have with your answer is that it's factually incorrect: "Just returning it FALSE won't prevent it from submitting" is not true

Comment: I'm referring to the onSubmit tag on the form itself that simply says "return false".  In any case, yes, I agree.  I think he is going for a validation, even though that was left out of the question.  That's why my answer points to a method of handling just that.

Comment: I see what you're saying now - but see the second code block in the question where he actually calls the function - the way he was attempting to do it was actually fine, apart from the aforementioned issues. Anyway, your edit resolves the issue I had with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jquery

```
$("#searchButton2").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('abort');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Eh4E8/2/)

Comment: post an answer that works and it gets 2 down votes with no explanation - thanks

Comment: I know that feel bro :) I think they are not searching for an alternative solution.

Comment: Probably because people can't agree on things like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/is-it-okay-to-post-answers-using-libraries-frameworks-extensions-not-already-men?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery.

```
$(function(){
    $('form.search').submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/U6UC3/